# Why does my C program output this?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, stringification

I am trying to solve two Preprocessor related questions but in both programs I am getting results that I am not able to figure out how. Below is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
int main()
{
float s=10,u=30 ,t=2,a;
a=2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t);
printf("Result:%f\n",a);
return 0;
}
```

According to me, the  output of this programme should be `-25.000` but I am getting `-100.000`.

And  in second program:

```
#define FUN(i,j) i##j
int main()
{
int val1 = 10;
int val12 = 20;
clrscr();
printf("%d\n",FUN(val1,2));
getch();
}
```

Output should be `102` but I am getting `20`;
why is it so?

Comment: I doubt that #include>stdio.h>
will even compile...

Comment: sorry @PhiLho its #include<stdio.h>

Comment: your second example will not compile. Please copy/paste the exact source code you used.

Comment: @Alexandrie i made a mistake in pasting the code now made it correct..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first one:

```
a=2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t);
```

after replacing the define we get:

```
a=2*(s-u*t)/t*t;
```

now, since we don't have `()` in the definition of SQUARE we get:

```
a=2*(10-30*2)/2*2; --> a=2*(-50)/2*2; --> a=-100/2*2; --> a=-50*2; --> a=-100
```

if you want to get `-25` you should define `SQUARE(x)` as `(x*x)`.

Edit : add explanation regarding the second example.

```
printf("%d\n"FUN(val1,2));
```

once again, we first should replace the define (reminder: ## "concatenates" the string of the define - I can't find the perfect words in order to explain it so just take a look at the example...):

```
printf("%d\n",val12);  [note: the comma (,) is missing - so it won't compile.]
```

since the value of `val12` is `20` that's what you'll get.

the point of those 2 examples is to remember that we should always deal with the defines first (since in "real life" the compiler (or pre-processor) does it before the run time)

I hope it helps..

Comment: thanks @SivGo for your explanation and and also the fact that / * operator has Associativity from left to right....

Comment: and could n't get the second problem yet

Comment: printf("%d\n",FUN(val1,2)); here value of val1 is not going to replace with 10 ??? that's where i got confused...i think it should replace by 10...

Comment: the first stage is taking care of the define and only then you "replace" variable name with its value, so by the time you get to that there is no val1 anymore only val12.

Comment: got it ,its preprocessing before any compilation

Answer (score 11):

```
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
```

should be

```
#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Indeed, without the parentheses, `2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t)` is expanded as

```
2*(s-u*t)/t*t
```

which is interpreted as

```
(2*(s-u*t)/t)*t
```

As to your second problem, `FUN(val1,2)` will get expanded as `val12` per the semantics of the `##` operator. It is still not clear what your intent is: the `printf` line will be understood as

```
printf("%d\n", val12);
```

which will print `20`.

Comment: Likewise for example two, `(i##j)`

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre. this a=(2*(s-u*t)/t)*t ; expression is according to #define SQUARE(x) x*x ,this what you want to say

Comment: why defining FUN like this : #define FUN(i,j) (i##j) would have solved the problem ?

Comment: @SivGo: The intent of the second example is not clear. Now that OP corrected his code, I update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the first case,

```
a=2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t);
```

would translate to

```
a=2*(s-u*t)/t*t;
```

at compile time. This is a common mistake made with preprocessors.

Answer (score 0):

i know i am late, but i am having the perfect answer.

in c # at define is used to call the text as it is in the function parameter,

example, #define hai(s1) printf("%s=%s",#s1,s1);

```
       in main: i am calling as hai(tom); tom was initialized as "india" string.
```

the output for this is tom=india, the calling string tom is printed by help of #.

similarly ## is used to take the text from function argument and join them and return the value of the joined identifier.

the above program has two argument va1 and 2. passed to i and j. then va1 and 2 is joined. and form va12.

va12 is the identifier available with value 20. that's why 20 is returned.